# Session variables not clearing

Tags: asp.net, gridview, session-variables

I have a search page where a user can enter search parameters and click a search button. The `ASP` application will then send the data to a stored procedure in a `SQL 2005` database. The results of the database search are then sent back to the `ASP` application and displayed in a gridresults page. The user then has an option to go back to the search page and do another search. The issue is that no matter what they enter, they do not get any results. I think the session variables are not clearing out. I tried to do this:

```
Session["Name"] = null;
```

and

```
 Session.Remove("Name");
```

I did both of these when the search page loads and when the button to go back to the search page is clicked. Neither seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Show your code @ first

Comment: what does session variable have to do with search result? What is the dependency? could it be that the database is returning no results?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you are clearing the session variables, but inadvertently setting it again somewhere else. Recheck every place you set the session values.

Comment: The issue ended up not being the session variable. It was in the way the search was created. Thank you everyone for your help.